# Automapper merge/combine mappings

Tags: c#, automapper-2

Let's assume I have these mappings:

```
var mapping1 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, BaseDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Referrer, m => m.Ignore());

var mapping2 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, DetailDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Price, m => m.Ignore());

var mapping3 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, UpdateDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Temp, m => m.Ignore());
```

Inheritance of Dtos:

`DetailDto : BaseDto`

`UpdateDto : BaseDto`

Is there any way to merge/combine the first mapping into mapping2 and mapping3?

Something like this:

```
var mapping1 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, BaseDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Referrer, m => m.Ignore());

var mapping2 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, DetailDto>()
    .Import(mapping1);
    .ForMember(o => o.Price, m => m.Ignore());

var mapping3 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, UpdateDto>()
    .Import(mapping1);
    .ForMember(o => o.Temp, m => m.Ignore());
```

The `.Include` function does not seem to do what I want as the following doesn't work:

```
var mapping1 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, BaseDto>()
    .Include<Order, DetailDto>()
    .Include<Order, UpdateDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Referrer, m => m.Ignore());

var mapping2 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, DetailDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Price, m => m.Ignore());

var mapping3 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, UpdateDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Temp, m => m.Ignore());
```

**Update**: Edited question to be more specific

Comment: And why can't you just do: var mapping1 = Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
    .ForMember(o => o.Referrer, m => m.Ignore()).ForMember(o => o.Price, m => m.Ignore());?

Comment: @Icarus It is a bit more complicated, because the mappings have different destinations. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if its a bug. The [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) states:

> In AutoMapper 2.0, this becomes:
>
> ```cs
> Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
>   .Include<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>()
>   .Include<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>()
>   .ForMember(o=>o.Id, m=>m.MapFrom(s=>s.OrderId));
> Mapper.CreateMap<OnlineOrder, OnlineOrderDto>();
> Mapper.CreateMap<MailOrder, MailOrderDto>();
> ```
>
> Because we have defined the mapping for the base class, we no longer have to define it in the child mappings.

I have just upgraded to `AutoMapper 2.2.1-ci9000` and I'm getting the same behaviour as you (ie, `Referrer` is not being ignored).

I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues) for it and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this comes a bit late, but for the benefit of someone else with similar issues...

I struggled with the same problem until I found [this page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance#inheritance-mapping-priorities) on the AutoMapper Github wiki.

In summary:

Inherited configuration is evaluated against priorities (to resolve issues where multiple maps have conflicting configuration for the same members). An `Ignore()` that is inherited has a lower priority than AutoMapper's standard convention-based mapping. So where the source and destination types both have a `Referrer` property, the convention-based mapping for the most derived types overrides the inherited `Ignore()`.

That suggests then, that in this instance, you need to repeat the `Ignore()` for the maps for each type derived from `BastDto`